# Killall -u and RedHat 3

Tags: linux, redhat, kill

I want to do a `killall -u` (for a specified user), but `-u` parameter doesn't exists under in RedHat 3. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `skill -u user -c process_name`

Thank you Ancosen

Comment: I'm glad to have been helpful. Next time remember to vote the correct answer. You've posted an answer to your own question and vote that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [skill](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?skill%201) in particular the `-u` option. I can't verify, because i haven't an available environment with Red Hat 3.

Or you can use a solution like this

```
ps aux | grep -ie user | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}'
```